# Tough function to integrate

Tags: integration

I am having trouble seeing the process to integrate this function (wrt T)

$$A(T) = \frac{1}{(CT^4)}\frac{(1-a)K+aT}{a(K-T)}$$

Should I use integration by parts? I do not see how this will work

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice observation:

$$\frac{(1-a)K+aT}{a(K-T)} = \frac{K-aK+aT}{a(K-T)} = \frac{K}{a(K-T)} - \frac{a(K-T)}{a(K-T)} = \frac{K}{a(K-T)}-1.$$

With this equality, we can see that what we really want to evaluate is then

$$\int \frac{1}{CT^4}\left(\frac{K}{a(K-T)}-1\right)\,dT.$$

Breaking this into two integrals since integrals are linear (and factoring out constants) gives

$$\frac{K}{aC}\int \frac{1}{T^4}\frac{1}{K-T}\,dt - \frac{1}{C}\int \frac{1}{T^4}\,dT.$$

The second integral is very doable. The first is as well but requires an application of partial fraction decomposition. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How does this include the T^4 term? Did you forget that term?

Comment: No, I purposefully didn't include it. I was just working with the "harder" term to make things easier for you.

Comment: Can I just multiply the integral of one times the integral of the other? Does it not need to be included?

Comment: I'll expand upon my answer so it's clear to you what is going on.

Comment: Ok thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: The second integral is easy - the first one I am not sure about. It's been years since I did PFD

Comment: To do PFD on this, you'll have to write $$\frac{1}{T^4}\frac{1}{K-T} = \frac{A}{T^4} + \frac{B}{T^3} + \frac{C}{T^2} + \frac{D}{T} + \frac{E}{K-T}$$ I believe and solve for the coefficients (then do the integrals).

Comment: I see but normally coefficients can be grouped and whatnot with like terms. It does not seem like there are many like terms here. I mean in this case, would A =1 and E = 1 and all others =0?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's pretty messy in this example. :/

Comment: If i multiply left side across, I just get 1 equals a bunch of stuff. I fail to see how I can solve for the coeffs

Comment: Are you positive this method will work?

Comment: Yep I am positive. What you will have to do is what is called "equating coefficients". You should make a new post about this so that others can help you. I'm about to call it a night.